# Reprojecting sources with MapProxy yields distortion

Tags: wms, coordinate-system, mapproxy

I have configured MapProxy to aggregate imagery from a number of Internet sources so that I can dynamically overlay them by adjusting the `layers=<x>` query that I pass to MapProxy's WMS service. This all seems to be working properly.

Here's the problem: some of the sources are TMS servers, which use the spherical Mercator (EPSG:900913) projection. Some of the others are WMS servers that only serve data in the EPSG:4326 (WGS84) projection. MapProxy is nice enough to handle this for me, caching the images in their native projection and then reprojecting them to the target projection when I request them. However, there is a great deal of distortion in the resulting images near the -180/+180 degree longitude line. Here's an example:

[image]

The source image is from MapQuest's Open Aerial service, which is in global Mercator. The above is MapProxy's reprojection of the source to EPSG:4326. For most of the globe, it looks great, but the rightmost part of the image is obviously way off. If I request it in its native projection, then I get a nice image:

[image]

I see very similar results if I take an EPSG:4326 source (Landsat images from [this WMS source](http://irs.gis-lab.info/)) and request it from MapProxy using EPSG:900913:

[image]

Am I missing something fundamental here? Is this to be expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this was a bug in v1.3.0 of MapProxy, and has been fixed. From the changelog for the pre-release version v1.4.0rc1:

```
- EPSG:4326/900913/3857 are now always initialized with the +over proj4
  option to prevent distortions at the dateline
  see: http://fwarmerdam.blogspot.de/2010/02/world-mapping.html
```

I updated to the new version and the reprojected output looks good:

[image]